# return View in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# and ASP.NET MVC and specially views.

I have the following problem

I have this code

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult ManageEmployee(int cntID, string command)
    {
        //repository = new ContactRepository();
        cntadrRepository = new ContactAddressCountryRepository();
        //addressRepository = new AddressRepository();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(command) && command.Equals("edit"))
        {

            var cdrcnts = cntadrRepository.GetById(cntID);

            ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
            //return View("_ManageEmployee", cdrcnts);
            return View("Index", cdrcnts);
            //return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.IsUpdate = false;
            //return View("_ManageEmployee");
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

that returns my form empty when I click on Add button

when I click on Add I get the form slide in and the grid slide out and I can enter a new record and then after clicking on save I return to my grid with the new record.

Now the problem is When I click on Edit I have the view with only an Add button that when I click on I get the result that I want to get, directly, when I click on Edit which is the form filled with the required information

I think that I have a problem when I return the view.

What I want is that I return that form populated with the contact information when I click on Edit and stay in the same page that shows again the grid and the edited record and not have that empty page with the Add button that I need to click on again to have the required result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would try an MVC walkthrough before (since you are new to MVC in .NET). Try: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Comment: if you want submit the changes and stand in the view without be redirect you have to post the form by ajax, and then reload your windows

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but can you please send me an example ?

Comment: @MailmanOdd thank you for the interesting link but I don't want to create a separate view for the edit form. I have one form and the Update function plays both roles : the Create and the Update. The Create works fine but when it comes to the Edit a new view is send which is not what I want. I want to stay in the same page with the same animations just the form will be populated instead of empty

Comment: @Antarr Byrd thank you for the interesting link but I don't want to create a separate view for the edit form. I have one form and the Update function plays both roles : the Create and the Update. The Create works fine but when it comes to the Edit a new view is send which is not what I want. I want to stay in the same page with the same animations just the form will be populated instead of empty

Comment: @Soussou please post the code for you view

Comment: @Soussou I understand, I am just telling you that is not considered good design for an MVC application.

Comment: @Soussou my suggestion would be include two seperate forms in your view. And only show one depending on which action is selected. Each form would then post to its own action.

Comment: @AntarrByrd This is my Grid
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ig.loader({
        scriptPath: './js/',
        cssPath: './css/',
        resources: 'igGrid.*',
        ready: function () {
        expandCollapseAnimations: true,
                    animationDuration: 1000,
                    height: "400px",
                    width: "800px",
                    dataSource: data,
                    responseDataKey: "Records",
                    autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                    autoGenerateColumns: false,
                    showReadonlyEditors: false,

Comment: @MailmanOdd I am sure you r right since this app os my first steps in MVC

Comment: @AntarrByrd I couldn't post the code because it is too long :/

Comment: @AntarrByrd but here is where I call my editors :  { headerText: headerTextValues[4], key: "UpdateRow", width: 175, template: "<button href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=${cntID}&command=edit' class='editDialog'>Edit</button>" },

Comment: sorry I am new to this form I couldn't post my code :/

Comment: @Soussou Sorry for the late response. Yesterday was the first day of class. Will try and get back to you when I can.

Comment: @Soussou It would be really helpful if you post to source for your view. This size shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ig.loader({
        scriptPath: './js/',
        cssPath: './css/',
        resources: 'igGrid.*',
        ready: function () {
            $.getJSON("Home/GetAll", null, function (data) {
                var headerTextValues = ["Relation to Will maker", "First Name", "Last Name","","",""];
                $('#employeeGrid').igGrid({
                    expandCollapseAnimations: true,
                    animationDuration: 1000,
                    expandTooltip: "Expand to View Details",
                    collapseTooltip: "Hide details",
                    height: "400px",
                    width: "800px",
                    dataSource: data,
                    responseDataKey: "Records",
                    //dataSourceType: "json",
                    autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                    autoGenerateColumns: false,

                    rowEditDialogContainment: "owner",
                    showReadonlyEditors: false,

                    columns: [
                        { headerText: headerTextValues[0], key: "cntID", width: 200 },
                        { headerText: headerTextValues[1], key: "cntFirstName", width: 175 },
                        { headerText: headerTextValues[2], key: "cntLastName", width: 175 },
                        //{ headerText: headerTextValues[3], key: "Age", width: 175 },
                        { headerText: headerTextValues[4], key: "UpdateRow", width: 110, template: "<a href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=${cntID}&command=edit' class='editDialog'>Edit</a>" },
                        { headerText: headerTextValues[5], key: "DeleteRow", width: 50, template: "<a href='Home/Delete?cntID=${cntID}' class='confirmDialog'><button>Delete</button></a>" },
                    ],

                    initialDataBindDepth: -1,
                    primaryKey: 'cntID',
                    width: '800',
                    updateURL: "Home/Update",

                    /*columnLayouts: [
                            {
                                key: "cntD",
                                responseDataKey: "Records",
                                autoGenerateColumns: false,
                                autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                                generateCompactJSONResponse: false,
                                primaryKey: "cntID",
                               foreignKey: "cntAddressID",
                                columns: [
                                    { key: "cntId", headerText: "Address Id", width: "150px" },
                                    { key: "cntAddressID", headerText: "Address", width: "150px" },
                                    //{ key: "Street", headerText: "Street", width: "150px" },
                                    //{ key: "City", headerText: "City", width: "150px" },
                                    //{ key: "Zip", headerText: "Zip", width: "150px" }
                                ]
                            }
                    ],*/

                    features: [
                            {
                                name: "Selection",
                                mode: "row",
                                multipleSelection: false
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Hiding'
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Paging',
                                type: 'local',
                                pageSize: 10,
                                inherit: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Filtering'
                            },
                            {
                                name: "ColumnMoving",
                                mode: "immediate",

                                //columnDragStart: function (event, ui) {
                                //    ui.owner.element.find('tr td:nth-child(' + (ui.columnIndex + 1) + ')').addClass("ui-state-moving");
                                //    colMovingKey = ui.columnKey;
                                //},
                                //columnDragEnd: function (event, ui) {
                                //    var grid = $(event.target).data('igGrid');
                                //    var newindex = grid.options.columns.indexOf(grid.columnByKey(colMovingKey)) + 1;
                                //    grid.element.find('tr td:nth-child(' + newindex + ')').removeClass("ui-state-moving");
                                //},

                                addMovingDropdown: true,
                                mode: "deferred",
                                type: "render"
                            }


                    ],
                });
            });
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-edit").load(url);
            $("#dialog-edit").toggle("slide");
        });

        $("#openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-create").load(url);
            $("#dialog-create").toggle("slide");
        })


    });


</script>
@section featured {
<section class="featured">
    <div class="overlap">
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <!-- the igHierarchicalGrid target element-->
        <table id="employeeGrid" style="width: auto;"></table>

        <p>
            <a id='openDialog' href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=0&command=create' class='openDialog ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only' style="color: white;">Add Employee</a>

        </p>
        <div id="btn">
        <button id="add">Add</button>
            </div>
```